# Is Environment.TickCount affected by system time adjustments?

Tags: .net, base-class-library

I'm curious as to how the .NET BCL property Environment.TickCount is implemented. In particular I'd like to now if it is affected by [system time adjustments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724943(VS.85).aspx).

My first guess as to how the property was implemented was that it was simply a managed wrapper around the [GetTickCount method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx). However, the documentation for the [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) method states that it is *affected by adjustments made by the GetSystemTimeAdjustment function* but the documentation for [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) does not mention anything about  time adjustments.

I'm trying to figure out if the Environment.TickCount can be used as a (albeit low-precision) consistently increasing time value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) is not affected by adjustments of the system time. That was my interpretation of the documentation, but my curiosity demanded harder proof, so I had the following code run while adjusting the system back and forth one hour:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.TickCount);
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
}
```

...and the output showed a perfect sequence that was not affected by the time adjustments.

**Update**
So I did some more homework, triggered by Marcus' question in the comments below. I am quite sure (could not confirm though) that Environment.TickCount makes a call to [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx) that has the following mentioned in the docs:

> The resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is limited to the resolution
>   of the system timer, which is
>   typically in the range of 10
>   milliseconds to 16 milliseconds. The
>   resolution of the GetTickCount
>   function is also affected by
>   adjustments made by the
>   GetSystemTimeAdjustment function.

So, while it is not affected by altering the system time, it seems that *will* be affected by adjustments that are caused by a call to [`SetSystemTimeAdjustment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724943(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: (lang:sv Tack!) Hey thanks, just curious though. Are you certain that system time adjustments (the incremental scary type described in the GetSystemTimeAdjustment docs where time runs faster or slower to catch up) really takes place when you set the time manually? Doesn't the system time simply jump to the correct time directly when you do that?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting that quote from? The MSDN page for [GetTickCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives me, "_GetTickCount function **is not** affected by adjustments made by the GetSystemTimeAdjustment function_"

Comment: Good catch, @ahmd0! I got curious, so I checked. It seems that the page was updated in August 2010 to change from my quote above, to what is there now. Makes me wonder what happened: was the docs wrong or did the behavior change?

Comment: @FredrikMörk: It must've been a typo.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not affected by system time adjustments.

Whether it's suitable for a "consistently increasing time value" depends on your exact requirements. From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx):

> The value of this property is derived
>   from the system timer and is stored as
>   a 32-bit signed integer. Consequently,
>   if the system runs continuously,
>   `TickCount` will increment from zero to
>   `Int32.MaxValue` for approximately
>   24.9 days, then jump to `Int32.MinValue`, which is a
>   negative number, then increment back
>   to zero during the next 24.9 days.