# C# Hook : System.Random

Tags: c#, random, hook, random-seed

I would like to monitor a software that uses the `System.Random` class. 
I would like to be able :
1/ to monitor the creation of all Random instances
2/ force the seed used by this instance
or 2bis/ force the result of the random to my own random

I would need the software to always behave the same, even on different computers, so I can better test my own software that communicates with it.

I have read EasyHook's tutorials, but I think they only mention function hooking, not class creation or class methods hooking.

Comment: I know I'll regret asking "but why do you want to 'hook' the System.Random class?" Never seen or heard of anyone wanting to do that.....

Comment: Are you trying to game a certain piece of software by hijacking the creation of the random numbers?

Answer (score 4):

The .NET framework offers no good mechanism to hook method calls.  The just-in-time compiler as well as the ngen.exe prejitter make this impossible to implement.  There no good way to obtain the address of the method nor any decent way to patch the code since this is done without any indirect jumps.  The kind of jumps that exist in the DLL import table that hookers like EasyHook depend on for example.

This needs to be messed with *before* the jitter sees the code.  Also the way that Aspect Oriented Programming tools like PostSharp do it.  They are IL rewriters, they modify the assembly before you run the code.  So the scheme is to replace calls to System.Random in the IL with a call to your method.  And add a dependency on your assembly.

"IL rewriting" is a good google search term to find implementations.

Answer (score 0):

"IL rewriting" seems to be your best option here, though might be possible to detect and alter the default instance creation if it's calling [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx) in kernel32:

```
public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount)
{
}
```

I don't really know if Environment.TickCount actually calls [GetTickCount()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx). But it is [plausible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858989/is-environment-tickcount-affected-by-system-time-adjustments).