# How in C # HttpClient calculate the time to send a request, time to wait for a response, and time to receive a response?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code

```
DateTime startSendRequest;
DateTime endSendRequest;
DateTime startWaitingResponse;
DateTime endWaitingResponse;
DateTime startGetResponse;
DateTime endGetResponse;
HttpResponseMessage response;

startSendRequest = DateTime.UtcNow;
var responseTask = HttpClient.GetAsync("Test/GetFile");
endSendRequest = DateTime.UtcNow;

startWaitingResponse = DateTime.UtcNow;
response = await responseTask;
endWaitingResponse = DateTime.UtcNow;

startGetResponse = DateTime.UtcNow;
var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\test\SampleFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
endGetResponse = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

It seems to me that the startWaitingResponse and endWaitingResponse variables are calculating the total response time (with download file), rather than waiting for a response.
Is it possible to calculate "waiting response for download" and "download time"?

Comment: (Assigning from `DateTime.UtcNow` twice in a row looks debatable. I don't like it for increased intrusiveness of timing like this.)

Answer (score 3):

Pass `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`:

```
startSendRequest = DateTime.UtcNow;
var responseTask = HttpClient.GetAsync("Test/GetFile", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
endSendRequest = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Side note: prefer using `Stopwatch` for timing things. <s>`DateTime.UtcNow` can jump forwards or backwards in time due to daylight savings time changes.</s> `DateTime.UtcNow` is not accurate for timing small amounts of time.

Comment: Actually UTC [is immune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62151/datetime-now-vs-datetime-utcnow/52625078#52625078) to daylight saving time adjustments. [I've made the same mistake myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68331666/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-concurrent-dictionary-from-being-used/68337246#comment120775575_68337246) recently.

Comment: thank you!))) it's work
Stopwatch is faster, but i need datetime